# How do I programatically add actions to an Action Manager in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, taction, tactionmanager

I am trying to dynamically add actionitems, I can add the item and it works when I do this:

```
HostActionItem := ActionManager.ActionBars[0].Items[0].Items[2];
  NewItem := HostAction.Items.Add;
  NewItem.Action :=  MyActionToPerform;
  NewItem.Caption := Description;
  NewItem.ImageIndex := 1;
  NewItem.Tag := 13;
```

However, when the action Execute method fires I attempt to get the ActionComponent from the Sender object like this:

```
  if (Sender is TAction) then
  tag := (Sender As TAction).ActionComponent.Tag;
```

But the ActionComponent is always nil. Why is the ActionComponent not being initialised?

Comment: _"Why is the ActionComponent not being initialized?"_ seems to be the real question here, instead of how to add actions to an action manager. By the way, try using the action `Tag` and if you need different tags for the same action, that maybe symptom you need another action, instead of creating a ["god" event handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: Sorry to confuse the question by phrasing it the way I have. Essentially you are correct. I am chasing a way of having dynamic actions and therefore need a fairly flexible event handler. Do you suggest creating the underlying actions dynamically as well or is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**short answer:**

You're expecting a `TActionClientItem` to show up as `ActionComponent` of an `TAction`. That won't happen since `TActionClientItem` does not descend from `TComponent`.

**longer answer:**

I believe you're adding your item to a menu bar. It seems to be by design that an `TAction` linked to a menu item would not support the `ActionComponent`. The items of a menu bar is of type [`TActionClientItem`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ActnMan_TActionClientItem.html). This is a 'collection item', not a 'component'. Hence the menu cannot fill in the `ActionComponent` parameter with the menu item when calling the [`Execute`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TBasicActionLink_Execute.html) method of the action link of the selected item. If this sounds confusing, I guess the below quotes from the VCL source would make it clear:

`TBasicActionLink.Execute` method:

```
function Execute(AComponent: TComponent = nil): Boolean; virtual;
```

The passed component is assigned to `FAction.ActionComponent` before it is executed.

How it's called from `TCustomActionMenuBar.ExecAction`:

```
FSelectedItem.ActionLink.Execute;
```

For the question in the title, I don't think you're doing anything wrong, apart from setting the `Caption` and `ImageIndex` of a `TActionClientItem` is unnecessary, as it's the `TAction`'s title and image which will be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I set the caption, imageindex & tag because I re-use the same action for multiple action links. Am I doing this the hard way? Is there a better way of trying to achieve dynamic action items?

Comment: @Leigh - I don't see any easier way.. add a client item and associate it with an action, that's about it. Note that if you reuse actions you won't be able to offer the built-in customization ability. And if you need to differentiate the source in OnExecute, the only way seems to be to use an action per item.

Comment: Thanks, I now just maintain separate actions for the dynamically created items and it works fine.