# work around for TActionMainMenuBar painting bug where item is not unselecting

Tags: delphi, menu, tactionmanager

TActionMainMenuBar have a bug with painting root elemetnts without child items.

Using Delphi XE2 / w7-32bit**

how to reproduce:
build menu with TActionMainMenuBar, add some actions to it:

```
 file  | options | help
 - New
 - Open
 - Save
  -Exit
```

assign to all actions one empty method

```
procedure TfrmMain.ActionExecute(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
// 
end;
```

now run application and try to click on options or help element.
now click on form, but the menu element is still pressed!

any workarounds exists?

upd: look at screenshot, menu element is down, but mouse cursor not on menu, and autocheck is false, and checked is false too. 
 [image]

  here is not any colormap on the form, and manager style is platform default

Comment: I don't see any problem/can't reproduce in Delphi 2009.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand are you assigned the empty method? please send me compiled exe, maybe we have some regression in XE2

Comment: I can reproduce this is XE2

Comment: What is supposed to happen? The `Options` menu item is disabled, and so nothing happens when you hover/click it...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand actOption.onexecute must be linked to empty method. just dblclick on it in objectinspector and add // to generated code

Comment: Same thing happens in Delphi 2010.  It should be noted that performing any kind of "visual" action in the event handler seems to solve the problem.  e.g.  `X:=1` in the action handler displays the same problem, `ShowMessage('Options')` does not.

Comment: @utmost: OK, I only believed that `New`, `Open`, `Save`, and `Exit` had to be linked to empty actions. Still, I don't see anything strange...

Comment: HOWEVER, if I use the 'XP Style' and click on some *other* Windows application, so that this form loses its focus, then the last-clicked root item is painted in black instead of gray, so I *do* see an issue, although not quite as severe as the one reported.

Comment: I now changed to the 'Twilight Color Map', and then I see the problem as the OP describes it. Yes, this is a problem. +1 on the Q.

Comment: A screenshot would of been good here to illustrate the paint bug you are talking about.

Comment: @Blobby screenshot attached now

Comment: look at the TThemedMenuButton.DrawBackground in Vcl.ThemedActnCtrls unit : StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(MenuStates[MouseInControl, Selected]), PaintRect); the problem in menustates flags? maybe it not updated in some place

Comment: Interesting. The default appearance of the `TActionMainMenuBar` looks different on my system (Delphi 2009, Windows 7 Home Premium, Aero).

Comment: WTF? here is another bug in TActionMainMenuBar? write in OnExecute  `ShowMessage( TAction(Sender).ActionComponent.ClassName );` and call action from ActionMainMenuBar button, u get the exception, but it works fine with ActionToolBar.

Comment: @utmost - Yeah, menu items don't support actioncomponent, that's how it is designed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287411).

Comment: @utmost - You're welcome. Please post your workaround as an answer (after removing from the question), then you can accept it as the solution (probably after a specific time period though). BTW, I can duplicate the problem you have described with items that have items here, you probably don't observe that however...

Answer (score 1):

here is my workaround: 
create custom class like this:

```
type
  TFastThemedButton = class(TThemedMenuButton)
  protected
    procedure DrawBackground(var PaintRect: TRect); override;
end;
```

...

```
procedure TFastThemedButton.DrawBackground(var PaintRect: TRect);
const
  MenuStates: array[Boolean {MouseInControl}, Boolean {Selected}] of TThemedMenu =
    ((tmMenuBarItemNormal, tmMenuBarItemPushed), (tmMenuBarItemHot, tmMenuBarItemPushed));
var
  BannerRect: TRect;
  StartCol, EndCol: TColor;
begin
   Canvas.Brush.Color := ActionBar.ColorMap.Color;
   Canvas.Font := ActionBar.Font;
   StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(MenuStates[MouseInControl, (State=bsDown)]), PaintRect);
end;
```

now in you TActionMainMenuBar.OnGetControlClass add this simple code, and set to buggy actionclients tag=-100

```
procedure TfrmActions.ActionMainMenuBar1GetControlClass(Sender: TCustomActionBar; AnItem: TActionClient; var ControlClass: TCustomActionControlClass);
begin
  if ControlClass.InheritsFrom(TCustomMenuButton) and then
   begin
    if (AnItem.Tag =-100) and (ControlClass = TThemedMenuButton) then
      ControlClass := TFastThemedButton;
   end;
end;
```

well, now all root items with -100 tag, works as we wish

Answer (score 0):

I am using the event MainMenuExitMenuLoop with MainMenu.RecreateControls on all forms with a menu. So far this removes the stuck selection from the menu items.